# How to get a .PYC to not close after getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .PYC script I sent to someone, and it's crashing and giving an error that i'm not getting on my end. Is there anyway I can get the window to not close when it crashes so I can read the error message?

Comment: Can we assume that the user is running this in a Windows environment, and the user is double-clicking the python script to run it?

Comment: Yes he is running windows and simply double clicking the .pyc file.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script from an already-open terminal. To do this, open a terminal/command prompt and type:

```
python script.pyc
```

For this to work, you need to have the python executable in your path. Google "How to edit environment variables on [Your OS]" and add `C:\PYTHON33`. (Or whatever the directory is that you have installed Python to.)

When the error message appears, the terminal window will stay open for you.

Comment: Just seen the remarkably similar answer to the question linked by Mark Hildreth.. Maybe you should do a little bit more research before posting a question next time? :)

Comment: Hi, I tried editing the environment variables but python still doesnt work in cmd.

Comment: @Wilson Could you provide me with the exact error message?